# Get the Default RETURN VALUE from a stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, ado.net

```
public int Test()
        {
            int result = 1;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                result = Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

The method starts out with result = 1 so I can see it changing to a 0 if the query is successful. I tested this and it does change from 1 to a 0. My question is, is this the correct way to get the default RETURN_VALUE from a stored procedure?

This also changed the value of result from 1 to 0. Why? The query hasn't run yet.

```
public int Test()
        {
            int result = 1;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTest", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
            returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            result = Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Yes it is - or does it no work for you?

Comment: The reason why I'm asking was because I had the result = Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value); BEFORE running the query and it changed the result variable from 1 to a 0. So I wasn't sure why that would happen, considering the execution of the query hadn't happened yet.

Comment: @user1336632 that's because the default value of the return will be 0.

Comment: The procedure only does a SELECT * ...nothing fancy. I'm just worried about return values here. I want to make sure when I run a stored procedure, that I know if it was successful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Although if your connection fails to open, you'll get an error in your `finally`

And if this is SQL Server, don't start your stored procedure names with sp